# How to load different code when viewing view-source:

Tags: javascript, php

I want to detect view-source: and add different html to it.
I have tried using this but its not working

```
 $url= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
 $needle = "view-source:";
 if (strpos($url,$needle)) { echo "You can not see me";

 }
 else {}
```

Comment: Simple answer: You can't. You can't stop a browser that can read the source (and it needs to in order to display the page) from allowing a user to read the source it received.

Comment: I need this because i want to change og:title while sharing the link and showing different while in view source

Comment: this site is the example https://www.miniquiz24.com/minigame?ml=428    check the source code and share the link on facebook and then see

Answer (score 2):

It's not "strictly possible" but depending on the situation, there are ways to stop it - no matter how many times you read "not possible".

If you are using a page as a passoff, you can block the viewing of source through the use of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.

Example: `page1.php` posts data to `page2.php` which secretly adds more data to post and uses javascript to autopost from `page2.php` to `page3.php`.

In such a case you can hide the source of `page2.php` by doing:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != 'https://yourwebsite.ccom/page1.php') {
} else {
    //add your form and javascript code to auto post
}
```

Doing this, if the user quickly tries to stop the browser and view source, they will see empty source code. Even if they "repost" the form data they would see no html source.

Of course this won't stop them from viewing it through an element inspector.

You could then add some js to block access to F12 such as:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which === 123){
        return false;
    }
});
```

And disable right click and shortcut keys using something like

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false" onkeydown="return false;" onmousedown="return false;">
```

However the user can still disable javascript, use plugins, or several other methods to still inspect. This is why I say not "Strictly possible".

Answer (score 0):

This is simply not possible. `view-source:` is just an [URI-scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View-source_URI_scheme) the browser adds to the URL know which action he has to perform in this specific window. This part won't get sent to the webserver in order to load this specific site.